# Query about Oracle 19c parameters

Tags: oracle19c

I am using Oracle 19.0.0 and fired below query.

```
SELECT * FROM V$SYSTEM_PARAMETER2
```

and found below properties are not present.

optimizer_adaptive_features
_optimizer_use_feedback

So my doubt is it is removed in Oracle 19c or renamed it?

I checked it google but no solid reference found.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A (very) quick search lead to a [My Oracle Support page](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Cloud/2187449_1.html) for `optimizer_adaptive_features`:

> #### Changes to adaptive features in 12.2
>
> In 12.2, the parameter `optimizer_adaptive_features` has been obsoleted, replaced by two new parameters, `optimizer_adaptive_plans` and `optimizer_adaptive_statistics`. The `optimizer_adaptive_plans` parameter controls whether the optimizer creates adaptive plans and defaults to `TRUE`. The `optimizer_adaptive_statistics` parameter controls whether the optimizer uses adaptive statistics and defaults to `FALSE`. The creation of automatic extended statistics is controlled by the table-level statistics preference `AUTO_STAT_EXTENSIONS`, which defaults to `OFF`.  (`AUTO_STAT_EXTENSIONS` can be set using `DBMS_STATS` procedures like `SET_TABLE_PREFS` and `SET_GLOBAL_PREFS`.)
>
> These defaults have been chosen to place emphasis on achieving stable SQL execution plans.
>
> #### Implementing 12.2 adaptive features behavior in 12.1.0.2
>
> The adaptive features changes in 12.2 are available in 12.1.0.2 through a pair of fixes:
>
> - Bug 22652097 splits the parameter optimizer_adaptive_features into two, as above, and disables adaptive statistics by default.
> - Bug 21171382 disables the automatic creation of extended statistics unless the statistics preference `AUTO_STAT_EXTENSIONS` is set to `ON`.

Comment: Regarding _optimizer_use_feedback is hidden parameter correct? i got this from http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_12c_hidden_undocumented_parameters.htm here but same not found for Oracle 19c.

Comment: @Developer I could not find any official documentation regarding `_optimizer_use_feedback` and whether its use is deprecated/obsolete in certain versions. If I had then it would have been included in the answer.